# Sping retry throws RetryExhaustedException when exception is not included in @Retryable

Tags: spring-retry

I am using spring-retry 1.2.5. In my code I am using @Retryable and @CircuitBreaker annotation but whenever there is an exception which is not mentioned in include attribute I am getting RetryExhaustedException instead of the thrown checked exception.

I found that we need to set the throwLastExceptionOnExhausted to true in RetryTemplate.

I added a RetryTemplate bean in the config class and set the property to true but at runtime
the created bean is not getting used. 
Basically @Retryable annotation is not using the bean which I created in configuration.

How can I set throwLastExceptionOnExhausted property when using @Retryable annotation ?

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of options.

1. Wire up your own interceptor bean and use it in the `@Retryable` `interceptor` property.
2. Add a `@Recover` method and re-throw the exception from there.

2 is probably the easiest.

Comment: The second option sounds good to have recovery method and rethrow the exception.  1. What if I have a retryable method with no argument and throws more than one exception, should I add overload recovery method in that case for specific exception ?                                                                           2. Can I use Retryable and Circuitbreaker annotations altogether on same method ? I need to have retry three times when circuit is closed and if three subsequent calls fails then circuit should get open and retry should not happen in circuit open state

Comment: 1. You can just add one `@Recover` method with `Throwable`. 2. I don't know; I will take a look on Monday if I have time.