# spring-retry : "Getting Retry exhausted after last attempt with no recovery path" with original exception on non retryable method

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-retry

I am trying to implement spring-retry(version - 1.3.1) in my spring boot application. I have to retry webservice operation to read the record if not found in first request.

sample code:

```
@Retryable(include = {IllegalArgumentException.class}, backoff = @Backoff(500), maxAttempts = 3, recover ="readFallback")
Object read(String Id);

@Recover
Object readFallback(RuntimeException e, String Id);

void deletePayment(String paymentId);
```

**Problem :**
I am getting correct response from read method(annotated with `@Retryable`) in exception scenario but I am getting `RetryExhaustedException` with nested original exception when I am getting exception on my delete method. As you see, delete method doesn't annotated with `@Retryable` . Delete method is in different package.

**Sample exception response ** : "Retry exhausted after last attempt with no recovery path; nested exception is exception.NotFoundException: Not found"

**Expected** : Delete method should not be impacted by `@Retryable`. Can someone help me to find what am i missing or doing wrong. I have tried but unable to not found the solution of this problem on internet.

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0):

Works as expected for me:

```java
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableRetry
public class So71546747Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(So71546747Application.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    ApplicationRunner runner(SomeRetryables retrier) {
        return args -> {
            retrier.foo("testFoo");
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
                retrier.bar("testBar");
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        };
    }

}

@Component
class SomeRetryables {

    @Retryable
    void foo(String in) {
        System.out.println(in);
        throw new RuntimeException(in);
    }

    @Recover
    void recover(String in, Exception ex) {
        System.out.println("recovered");
    }

    void bar(String in) {
        System.out.println(in);
        throw new RuntimeException(in);
    }

}
```

```
testFoo
testFoo
testFoo
recovered
testBar
java.lang.RuntimeException: testBar
    at com.example.demo.SomeRetryables.bar(So71546747Application.java:52)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:344)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:198)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:789)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:753)
    at org.springframework.retry.annotation.AnnotationAwareRetryOperationsInterceptor.invoke(AnnotationAwareRetryOperationsInterceptor.java:166)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:753)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:698)
    at com.example.demo.SomeRetryables$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$e61dd199.bar(<generated>)
    at com.example.demo.So71546747Application.lambda$0(So71546747Application.java:26)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:768)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunners(SpringApplication.java:758)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:310)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1312)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1301)
    at com.example.demo.So71546747Application.main(So71546747Application.java:17)
```

Please provide an [MCRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that exhibits the behavior you see so we can see what's wrong.

Comment: My problem is similar to the question [link]https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62087445/sping-retry-throws-retryexhaustedexception-when-exception-is-not-included-in-re . 
I have tried the suggestion 2 :
`code`
    @Recover
    public Object fallback(Throwable throwable)
Now, I am not getting the  ExhaustedRetryException on delete method but getting the ExhaustedRetryException on same service class read and update methods. Read and update are non retryable methods. I am also using the CircuitBreaker in my project.
Will above explanation helpful or do you need MCRE to reproduce?
Thanks

Comment: I can't guess what you are doing wrong without having some code to play with.